# How to enable federated engine in mysql? Missing my.cnf file

Tags: php, mysql, federation

I have found multiple solutions on stackoverflow, however none seemed to work as I don't have the my.cnf file, (except under the mysql folder I have one, but it doesnt have [mysqld] section.) Not really sure what else to check.

I just purchased a server. I have installed,
-apache
-mysql
-php
-phpmyadmin
all on Ubuntu 20.10 x64

Trying to create a link between this server and another server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find it myself. It is under the folder:
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d

File Name: mysqld.cnf

I then proceeded with adding federated to the below info:

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
# pid-file  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
# socket    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
# port      = 3306
# datadir   = /var/lib/mysql
federated
```